# How can I fetch data in autosuggest textbox from server/database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have created an autosuggest textbox that is fetching data from defined array.How can I make it fetch data from server?

Following is my code-

HTML code-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript files are of too much length.I can't paste them here.

Comment: you're using jQuery autocomplete, here's the docs: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: Agree with @rlatief don't be a help vampire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways in which you can populate an autocomplete box with data from your server. One of the easiest way to do so is, retrieve the data from your server and store it locally, and then use it.

```
var searchData = [];
$.get("ajax/mydata", function( data ) {
  searchData.push(data);
});
```

And then, carry on with the autocomplete part.

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
      source: searchData, 
      ...
});
```

Also, have a look at the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

ps. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it works for you.